# How to connect to Heroku Redis with SSL in C# .NET (Redis.StackExchange)?

Tags: c#, .net, heroku, redis, heroku-redis

The following code in C# works for connecting to Heroku Redis **without encryption** (free tiers):

```cs
var redisUrlString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_URL");
var redisUri = new Uri(redisUrlString);
var userInfo = redisUri.UserInfo.Split(':');
var redisConnString = $"{redisUri.Host}:{redisUri.Port},password={userInfo[1]}";
var redisConn = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnString);
var redisDb = redisConn.GetDatabase();
redisDb.StringGet("test");
```

When Heroku Redis is upgraded to any commercial tier, **encryption is required** and the code above fails with timeout, while with the following error message appears in the Heroku logs:

`app[redis-asymmetrical]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

When the code is modified by adding `ssl=true` to the connection string:

```cs
var redisUrlString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_URL");
var redisUri = new Uri(redisUrlString);
var userInfo = redisUri.UserInfo.Split(':');
var redisConnString = $"{redisUri.Host}:{redisUri.Port},password={userInfo[1]},ssl=true";
var redisConn = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnString);
var redisDb = redisConn.GetDatabase();
redisDb.StringGet("test");
```

It still doesn't doesn't work and the error is now different:

`app[redis-asymmetrical]: Error accepting a client connection: (null)`

What am I missing?